# Extension to Leibniz integral rule

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I want to differentiate an integral, where things are a bit more complicated than the standard Leibniz integral rule. The integral is shown below:

$\frac{d}{dz} \int_a^b f(y(x),z(x)) dx$

Here the limits are constants, and hence not a worry. However, the differentiating variable $z$ is itself is a function of the primary variable $x$.

Please suggest how to proceed such expressions.

Comment: It looks to me like the integral will just be a  *number*, and that's perhaps not what you intend.  Try $a = 0$, $b = 1$, $f(y,z) = y+z$, $y(x) = x$, and $z(x) = x^2$.  The resulting integral is $\int_0^1 (x + x^2)\,dx$. Do you see this is just a number?  It is quite different from $\int_0^1 (x + z)\,dx$, which is a function of $z$. I think you are confused about what you want and that your so-called "extension" is just going to be the usual Leibnize rule if you formulate your task more clearly.